# Dynamic creation of Wizard forms

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am new to client side coding. Is there a way in JavaScript from which we can create wizards dynamically.
For example just by giving the names of the text fields ,can I generate the form wizard ?
Is it possible using Javascript ,Reactjs,Bootstrap?

What I want to achieve by this is : incase I want to just provide the names and the types of form field required, can I generate a wizard?

Comment: See [react-bootrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

Comment: I am new to react js ! but familiar with bootstrap. anything u can suggest in   that?

Comment: React is nice, but you must understand that it works with its virtual DOM. It is not easy to work with react + jQuery + bootstrap, since jQuery modifies the actual DOM. Besides, if you have to use vanila bootstrap, to create your own react components you will be inventing a wheel that already exist. Since you are familiar with bootstrap use the react-boostrap components. See the documentation link in my previous comment to see how each components is to be used.